# Google charts material design with area charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I've been using [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/) for my web graphs.
As far as I know, there are some charts with material design and some others with the classic design.

I am currently working with [Line Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart), which have a material design. Now, I want to change all my Line Charts with [Area Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart), which are essentially the same, but the lines have a shade.
The only problem is that Area Charts do not have a material design.

This is my Line Chart:
[image: Line chart]

And this is how it would look like with the Area chart type:
[image]

You can notice the material design changes in the tooltip, the legend and the info on the axis.

So, my question is: is there a way I can have those shades of the Area Chart but using a Line Chart?
What I want is to have those shades, but to not lose the Material design experience.

Thanks!

Comment: No Currently their is no such functionality, i have gone through the same issue.